# Srping Batch - easiest way to get aggregated data (read, writes, step exit status, job exit status) from multiple Jobs/Steps run in the past

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application that runs 1 Job and 1 Step (The step that does some Reading, Processing, and Writing to a database). The JobParameters are the fileName (of the CSV) and the AWS region (the Spring Batch job starts when the CSV is loaded to a AWS S3 bucket). The issue is that another team is triggering the batch job nightly (using script to load CSV to S3 bucket), which kicks off a Job (reading data from CSV). This takes up to an hour(s), and this repeats several times through the night (up to ~7 Jobs).

***I know*** I can use the JobExecutionListener or StepExecutioner listener to get the metadata of the Job/Step **AS IT IS OCCURING**, but however since they are running multiple jobs, I would like aggregate a report that spans all of these jobs, and I can provide the read/write counts, exit status of both Job and Step. I also want to be able to do this AFTER, so I shouldn't be dependent on the Job/Step being currently running, like how the jobExecution/stepExecution get their data in the StepExecutionListeners (as I understand it).

I did see the **JobExplorer** bean, however, all the methods look like you need to have information like the JobId before grabbing the record from metadata tables, **which I would NOT have** after all the 7 jobs are run, unless I suppose I was saving it somewhere. I suppose I could create a few @Entities to represent the metatable tables (batch_job_execution, batch_step_execution, etc..) and then use the Jpa methods to query them by, say, the JobParameters (which I would have, since the team loading the CSV files would have that data, but not the JobInstanceId as I stated before). This seems a bit overkill though.

What is the easiest way to simple grab a specific set of Jobs and then from the Job, get the Step data, of Jobs/Steps that happened in the past? By "past",  I mean, maybe I will create a HTTP endpoint within my Spring Batch application where a user can post the fileName, and then all the metadata for that respective Job/Step can be returned, many minutes/hours/days after the actual Job/Step has completed.

Am I over complicating this? Is there an easier way?

Ideally, my "report" would look like something below, and maybe if it is triggered via HTTP Controller in my Spring Batch application, then I can also use JavaMail or JakartaMail to send to users invested in whether this data was loaded successfully or not:

```
mailSubject: BATCH JOB 07/06/2021 04:07:50 completed with STATUS {exitCode=COMPLETED}

mailBody:
job [myCustomSpringBatchJob] with step [myCustomSpringBatchStep] for fileName [dummyFileName1.csv] completed with STATUS [COMPLETED] read 320,343 / write 320,343

job [myCustomSpringBatchJob] with step [myCustomSpringBatchStep] for fileName [dummyFileName2.csv] completed with STATUS [EXECUTING] read 20,343 / write 400,343

job [myCustomSpringBatchJob] with step [myCustomSpringBatchStep] for fileName [dummyFileName3.csv] completed with STATUS [FAILED] read 23 / write 24

job [myCustomSpringBatchJob] with step [myCustomSpringBatchStep] for fileName [dummyFileName4.csv] completed with STATUS [COMPLETED] read 200,778 / write 200,778
```

As you can see, it will be an aggregated report on the specific Jobs run. The HTTP endpoint could accept a POST request something like this:

**HTTP POST**, `http://base-url/getBatchReport`

```
{
    "fileNames": [dummyFileName1.csv,
             dummyFileName2.csv,
             dummyFileName3.csv,
             dummyFileName4.csv
       ],
    "mailingList": [johndoe1@gmail.com,
             heatherjack@hotmail.com,
             mrsmithers@nike.com
             ]                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did see the JobExplorer bean, however, all the methods look like you need to have information like the JobId before grabbing the record from metadata tables

`JobExplorer#getJobInstances` takes a job name (and a count) and gives you the job instances corresponding to your job. In your case, you can do something like:

```
List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances("myCustomSpringBatchJob", 0, 10);
```

This will give you the job instances that you are looking for (one job instance per file and/or region if region is an identifying job parameter). From there, you can filter the job instances by looking at their parameters, execution times, etc and drill down to job executions and step executions to create the aggregate report.